# Wordpress - Changing when masonry is fired

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, masonry

I'm having a moment of stupidity and wondered f you could help.

I have a custom post type called "testimonials". I have a page displaying these posts. I'd like to use masonry (now bundled in Wordpress) to take care of a 2 column layout I have.

I worked through [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-use-masonry-to-add-pinterest-style-post-grid-in-wordpress/) but it has images involved and I don't.

I have this code

```
<script>
  //set the container that Masonry will be inside of in a var
  var container = document.querySelector('.testimonial-boxes');
  //create empty var msnry
  var msnry;
  // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
  imagesLoaded( container, function() {
      msnry = new Masonry( container, {
          itemSelector: '.testimonial-box'
      });
  });
</script>
```

In the browser console I have this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: imagesLoaded is not defined`

How would I adjust the code above to not wait for the images to be loaded?

Thanks

### [UPDATE]

I put the script in it's own .js file and in my `functions.php` imported the script using `wp_enqueue_script` as shown below.

`wp_enqueue_script('testimonial-masonry', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/testimonial-masonry.js', array( 'masonry' ), '1.0', true );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the `imagesLoaded()` function - your code should look like this

```
<script>

  //set the container that Masonry will be inside of in a var
  var container = document.querySelector('.testimonial-boxes');
  //create empty var msnry
  var msnry;

  // initialize Masonry
  msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.testimonial-box'
  });

</script>
```

The `imagesLoaded()` function had the masonry initialisation inside a completion block - `function(){ ... }` so all you need to do is remove this and everything around it.

**UPDATE: The error was resolved by moving the function call to after the masonry include.**

Comment: Hi Wezly, I thought that as well, but when I change it to that I get the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Masonry is not defined`. Does Masonry have to be declared as a `var`? The masonry js file is being pulled in at the footer.

Comment: You will need to include the masonry.js before the script runs - either put it in the header or move your script below the include.

Comment: Yep, I put my code in a separate js file and used `wp_enqueue_script` to pull it in dependant on `masonry`. Working fine now. Thanks for your help.